# How to plot more data points on D3.js as you zoom in?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am developing a few graphs by using D3.js and I am facing a few issues as I am not really familiar with the framework yet.

My main requirement is to plot a graph of price X time and my data points could be over a million data points in one day. So my idea was to use a similar approach to what google maps does. Every time you make a zoom in, maps takes more data from the server and display it. I would do the same by taking a few points to draw the chart and as you go zooming in I would take more points and making the chart sharper. How can I archive this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could interlink the number of data points plotted with the zoom factor by  using the zoom as a modulus. For example, let's say your zoom has 10 levels with 10 being the most zoomed out (earth in Google maps) and 1 the most detailed view (a single house) and assuming this function:

```
var scatter = d3.select("#svg").selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return y(d.y);
  })
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return x(d.x);
  })
  .attr("r", function(d, i) {
    return i % zoom == 0 ? 3 : 0; // <== This is _the_ line.
  });
```

The marked line goes through the data points and only if `i % zoom == 0` the drawn circle will have a radius of 3, all other circles get 0 and thus are not visible.

Of course, this still goes through all of the data points available but I think there was something like `.defined()` in d3 to avoid getting a data point drawn. The same function as above could be used there.

Comment: Thanks @Paul that gave a direction to my issue but I would like to get the data points as I zoom in, do you know any tricks to do that? The problem that I have is my data set is way too big to transfer and also to plot at the same time so I wanna 'skip' a few points and only show the whole points when I get to the last level of the zoom.

Comment: That can't be done efficiently with D3.js alone (imho), but requires an ajax request, so the server can prepare the data to be plotted and only transfer these data points to the client's browser.